# windows 7 home premium extract all command prompt fix results in no images only numbers

Tags: windows-7, windows, extract

there was no "extract all " command on my computer to extract zipped files.  I found a command prompt fix which was 
regsvr32 /u /s zipfldr.dll then hit Enter   Next type in the following regsvr32 /i /s zipfldr.dll then hit Enter 
now i cannot see any picture images, only numbers.   Can I reverse what I did?  I am no expert. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No permanent harm was done. regsvr32 just tells Windows where a DLL lives, and you "ininstalled" the Zip Folder DLL. To reverse it, open a CMD prompt and change directory to the location of that DLL, e.g.

> **cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64**

and press Enter. Then type

> **regsvr32 zipfldr.dll**

and press Enter. You should see a confirmation that the DLL was registered. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx for more information.

Comment: Hi Dr Moishe,   thank you very much for replying.  Its a friend of mine who has this problem, he is hopeless at computers and I'm just useless.  To give you a bit more info, the files that changed to numbers were only in his Downloads . They had the filename of combo followed by numbers like this: (2)

Comment: Hi Dr Moishe,   thank you very much for replying.  Its a friend of mine who has this problem, he is hopeless at computers and I'm just useless.  To give you a bit more info, the files that changed to numbers were only in his Downloads . They had the filename of combo followed by numbers like this: (2)  To reverse it, does he type exactly as you have shown?   We dont know the location of the DLL, all i can tell you is what he typed into command prompt. the file type of the numbered files was File  Can I attach a screenshot on here? if so, how?

Comment: sorry made mistake read second comment first.  I did an  edit  but it took over 5 mins but appears here

Comment: You'll have to find the DLL; it is most likely in **C:\Windows\SysWOW64** and you can open Windows Explorer and look in that folder. If not, change the **cd** to the correct location. **cd** means *change directory*. The second line does not need editing.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  Just to be sure, my friend is looking for regsvr32 zipfldr.dll  and the most likely folder is C:\Windows\SysWOW64.    If its there, he follows your 2 lines of instruction.   2 questions.  How important are spaces between characters? there is one between the 32 and zipfldr.  Next, if he cant find the DLL where you suggest, how many other folders are there that it might be in and where are they? Sorry to be so dumb, thanks again

Comment: No, he is looking for **zipfldr.dll** only; he types **regsvr32 zipfldr.dll**. Copy and paste, if your concerned about spacing.

Comment: I remembered On Jan 15 I d/l a prog   Free Viewer, to open a file in an email.I was suspicious  it was not from who it said, the file  was a form asking for bank info The type was a Free Viewer association (.html)

  I have animation prog  PAP,  has files that are image cutouts.    files only used by PAP  had  extension .cut
now type changed to Free Viewer Association.  they work as before.now see in  Downloads is Default_Zip. Jan 17.  did not d/l it. opens with Registry editor.   what  is it?  can it zip automatically?  dont want that. what shall I do?